# OAuth Token API Not Working In Elastic Search

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, oauth-2.0, kibana

I'm new to Elastic search. Integrated my Spring boot application with Elastic search through `Java High Level Rest Client` and I've enabled security by providing below properties after setting up the certificate and passwords:

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: "http.p12"
```

I've done the required changes in kibana.yaml as well and I'm able to access it.
Tried below call through Kibana to get the OAuth token:

```
   POST /_security/oauth2/token
    {
      "grant_type" : "password",
      "username" : "elastic",
      "password" : "password_for_elastic_super_user"
    }
```

Getting below error after executing in kibana:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "security_exception",
        "reason" : "current license is non-compliant for [security tokens]",
        "license.expired.feature" : "security tokens"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "current license is non-compliant for [security tokens]",
    "license.expired.feature" : "security tokens"
  },
  "status" : 403
}
```

I've hit the [GET license API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-license.html) as well, got below response:

```
{
  "license" : {
    "status" : "active",
    "uid" : "62b089de-422e-41f0-88c8-9ad76b27cd62",
    "type" : "basic",
    "issue_date" : "2020-06-25T07:17:48.310Z",
    "issue_date_in_millis" : 1593069468310,
    "max_nodes" : 1000,
    "issued_to" : "elasticsearch",
    "issuer" : "elasticsearch",
    "start_date_in_millis" : -1
  }
}
```

**Can anyone please help how to fix this?**

Comment: Try invoking via postman once. Add a basic authentication. Do pass `grant_type` in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `basic` version of elasticsearch which doesn't have this security feature(security tokens) and causing this issue, you can refer more to what is included in what license under Elastic stack security section in [Elastic subscription](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions).

`security tokens` feature is not available under the basic license as mentioned in the same subscription page and available from the gold tier.

[image]

Confirmed above from the [elasticsearch x-pack source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/x-pack/plugin/security/qa/security-basic/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/security/SecurityWithBasicLicenseIT.java#L180) as shown this exception is thrown while running the Integration test and this is the [production java code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/x-pack/plugin/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/license/LicenseUtils.java#L26) which throws the generic exception message for `current license is non-compliant for`.

**You have to upgrade to minimum Gold tier if you want to use `security tokens` feature.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How to change the license type to basic?

Comment: @DevChauhan got it updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try via postman :

1. Authorization : `Basic Auth`
2. Body : `grant_type`

[image: Reference :]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried but got the same error as in Kibana.

Comment: Can you try by setting xpack.security.enabled: false. Don't forget to do a restart after config change.

Comment: that will defeat the purpose of security implementation! There should be some missing thing that's why getting this error.

Comment: Error says that the `license of Xpack is expired`. So, It's recommended to either apply a free Basic license or disable the xpack.security.

Comment: A basic license is not entitled to security features. To try out security you need to use a trial license

Comment: Thanks, can you help on how to get trail license?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216703/discussion-between-dev-chauhan-and-amit-kumar).

Comment: Tried by disabling security... getting below Exception:  Invalid index name [_security], must not start with '_'

Comment: {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason" : "Invalid index name [_security], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "_security"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "invalid_index_name_exception",
    "reason" : "Invalid index name [_security], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "_security"
  },
  "status" : 400
}

Comment: To use : POST /_security/oauth2/token, you must have the manage_token cluster privilege. Read more here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-get-token.html

Comment: Already checked... I have that access... using superuser "elastic"

Comment: please check this, just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592786/get-oauth-token-api-not-working-in-elastic-search-even-security-is-disabled

Comment: Yeah! With version 7.X they have changed a bit. Glad that you got what you were looking for.