# OAuth Token API Not Working In Elastic Search Even Security Disabled

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, oauth-2.0, kibana

I'm new to Elastic search, using Elastic search version 7.7.1

I want to generate OAuth token by following [Elastic Search documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/security-api-get-token.html)

When I've Tried below call through Kibana to get the OAuth token as per documentation:

```
 POST /_security/oauth2/token
    {
      "grant_type" : "password",
      "username" : "elastic",
      "password" : "password_for_elastic_super_user"
    }
```

then getting below Error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason" : "Invalid index name [_security], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "_security"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "invalid_index_name_exception",
    "reason" : "Invalid index name [_security], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "_security"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

**Can anyone please help how to fix this?**

Comment: You need security enabled in your elasticsearch node. What do your `elasticsearch.yml`  config looks like? Update your question with it.

Comment: if I enable security then another issue occurs, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575068/get-oauth-token-api-not-working-in-elastic-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch creates the special index called `.security-7` in version 7.X when x-pack security is enabled by setting `xpack.security.enabled: true` and to access this index, you need to give `_security` as index name when calling the security API like creating role, users etc

Below is one such example where I created the `test` role when x-pack security is enabled.

endpoint http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/_security/role/test // notice `_security`

```
{
    "indices": [
        {
            "names": [
                "ngram*"
            ],
            "privileges": [
                "all"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: In your case, it would not work unless x-pack-security is enabled and you can't create `_security` index as its a special index which can be started with `_` and is created by x-pack only.